# AWS Java Lambda - dynamically loading jar from lambda - is it possible for jar/class collision?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a java lambda running in aws. I have a simple code that loads a jar that I download each run from the net:

```
            URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                    new URL[]{myJar.toURI().toURL()}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
            Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName(className, true, urlClassLoader);
            Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", String.class);
            method.invoke(null,"some data");
```

Is it possible that if I have several executions of my aws lambda at the same time (and of course each execution downloads the jar from the network - and the jar might be modified all the time before I download it) to have collision between class versions? Is it possible for different executions to use the same class loaders?

(I tried to test it first and had no class loader issues)

thanks for the help

Comment: I'm pretty sure each Lambda execution should be a separate process and thus have its own separate classloader. But I'd rethink the approach to download the jar on each run (or to even download it at all) because that seems to be expensive as it might drastically increase the Lamba's run time (of course this would also depend on how often the lambda would get called).

Comment: No, different executions do not hit the same execution environment. There cannot be two executions using the same class loader because they ran in different processes, on different virtual machines.

Comment: @luk2302 according to aws documentation (for nodejs) they might use the same container https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/ so I was wondering if that might be the case for java as well, as I do not want my dynamically loaded jars to collide.

Comment: But only one after the other, not in parallel. If you do stuff now that breaks an execution in 20 minutes because you mess up the class loader of your container / jvm that is unrelated to AWS lambda.